# Selecting column before nth breaks group indices

Tags: python, pandas

I try to extract the column `c` from the first of each group's rows, but struggle to understand why the group indices aren't preserved with the `g['c'].nth(0)` approach. Any idea?

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 1, 2, 2], 'b': ['b', 'b', 'b', 'a'], 'c': [1, 2, 3, 4]})
>>> g = df.groupby(['a', 'b'])
>>> g.nth(0)
     c
a b   
1 b  1
2 a  4
  b  3
>>> g['c'].nth(0)
0    1
2    3
3    4
Name: c, dtype: int64
>>> 
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 1, 2, 2], 'b': ['b', 'b', 'b', 'a'], 'c': [1, 2, 3, 4]})
>>> g = df.groupby(['a', 'b'])
>>> g.nth(0)
     c
a b   
1 b  1
2 a  4
  b  3
>>> g['c'].nth(0)
0    1
2    3
3    4
Name: c, dtype: int64
>>> g.nth(0)['c']
a  b
1  b    1
2  a    4
   b    3
Name: c, dtype: int64
>>>
```

Why does `g.nth(0)['c']` and `g['c'].nth(0)` does not return the same Series (including indices)?

**Update**

Interesting observation:

```
>>> g['c'].first()
a  b
1  b    1
2  a    4
   b    3
Name: c, dtype: int64
```

This does exactly what I want and behaves different to `g['c'].nth(0)`.

Comment: try `g['c'].head(1)`

Comment: That's returning the first _n_ items. I want one (the first) item from each group.

Comment: head(1) only returns the first row. isn't that what you want?

Comment: @SteveMisuta: No, the first row from each _group_ (and in fact not the complete row but just column `c`).

Comment: @jezrael changed his response. It was `g.head(1)` before (or at least I read it this way).

Answer (score 1):

I add new column `d` for better testing:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import io


df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 1, 2, 2], 'b': ['b', 'b', 'b', 'a'], 'c': [1, 2, 3, 4], 'd': [1, 2, 3, 4]})
print df
#   a  b  c  d
#0  1  b  1  1
#1  1  b  2  2
#2  2  b  3  3
#3  2  a  4  4
g = df.groupby(['a', 'b'])

#return SeriesGroupBy object and then apply nth
print g['c'] 
#<pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy object at 0x0000000014ED4EF0>
print g['c'].head()
#0    1
#1    2
#2    3
#3    4
#Name: c, dtype: int64
print g['c'].nth(0)
#0    1
#2    3
#3    4
#Name: c, dtype: int64
```

```
#return dataframe and then select c
print g.nth(0) 
#     c  d
#a b      
#1 b  1  1
#2 a  4  4
#  b  3  3
print g.nth(0)['c']
#a  b
#1  b    1
#2  a    4
#   b    3
#Name: c, dtype: int64
```

EDIT:

> why I need to apply nth to the whole grouped dataframe

Because you need first apply function [`nth`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.nth.html) for all group and then get first rows of group. I try it in second approach.

In first approach you simply passes the `C` column to a `Series GroupBy object` along with the already-computed grouping(s) [link](http://wesmckinney.com/blog/groupby-fu-improvements-in-grouping-and-aggregating-data-in-pandas/) (look for `New: Column selection`).
It is together `df.groupby(['a', 'b'])['c']` and then apply function `nth`. Not for all group `df.groupby(['a', 'b'])`.

I think there are chained functions and it depends on ordering of functions.

EDIT1:

Last I report it - it looks like a [bug](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/11830).

Comment: Check the grouping I applied. This isn't answering my question.

Comment: What is the result that you want to obtain? can you post the result by constructing it manually?

Comment: @jezrael: Your first block isn't applicable to my question as the group index is not present (I want to maintain this). In your 2nd example, I don't understand why I can't just do `g['c'].nth(0)` and why I need to apply `nth` to the whole grouped dataframe and _then_ select `c`.

Comment: @SteveMisuta: `g.nth(0)['c']` does exactly what I want, but the question is why isn't `g['c'].nth(0)` just doing the same thing? Selecting column c (`g['c']` somehow seems to lose the group index which is strange).

Comment: Yes its interesting, but see my answer below I think that explains why.

Comment: @jezrael: Your link and the example is more an example for why this behaviour is inconsistent. See `df2.groupby('A')['C'].mean()` (from your link) which returns the a series with proper (grouped) indices. `g['c'].nth(0)` however doesn't! I consider `nth` and `mean` as aggregation functions, so they should behave in the same fashion (it's just that `nth` is "aggregating" by returning _a_ element of the group). But perhaps there's something in the internals that forced the authors to go with the current behaviour...